# Max-width property on an image

Tags: html, css

Having a problem with the size of containers outside of a `max-width` image and the image itself is not taking up to 60% scale. I Can't show the image scaling issue due to not having a dynamic parent. Remove width/height from #container to see the issue. (Please note I am viewing this on a mobile device)

```css
#container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#img-container {
  position: relative;
}

#img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 60%;
}

#leftover {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stackoverflow example</title>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="img-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x1024.png" width="100%">
      </div>
    
      <div id="leftover">
        <h1>Should only have 40% leftover after the img-container takes up 60%.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `id="img-container"` instead of `class="img-container"`

Check your CSS.

`#img-container` = `id="img-container"`

`.img-container` = `class="img-container"`

```
<div id="img-container">
        <image src="http://placehold.it/1024x1024.png" width="100%">
      </div>
```

Comment: Oops, unfortunately that didn't fix the issue at hand, actually broke it even more?

Comment: what exactly do want to output?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
#img-container img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 60%;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really matter, and `<image>` is even mapped to `<img>` in HTML5 tree maps, but I fixed it. Ionic uses `<image>` in its examples.

Answer (score 0):

you can try tweaking the css a little bit as follows:

```
html,body{
height: 100%
}

.container{
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#img-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 60%;
}

img{
  max-height: 100%
}

#left-over{
    background: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    color: white;
}

h1{
  margin: 0;
}
```